# Transform Lightbox 'Close' button into Download button

Tags: javascript, jquery, download, lightbox2

I'm using the lightbox2 javascript on my webpage, but I'd like to know if there is a way to transform the close button into a download button. The reason I don't use `title="<a href>...</a>"` is because it screws up my php: I can just drop the photo's in a folder and the website does the rest.

So, I found the code for exiting the overlay, with `.lb-close` for the close-button-class...

```
  $lightbox.find('.lb-loader, .lb-close').on('click', function(e) {
    _this.end();
    return false;
  });
```

Lightbox2 Code:
https://raw.github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/master/js/lightbox.js

p.s. I tried using other scripts for my gallery, but that forces me to rebuild the whole page, which takes an awful lot of time...

Comment: If you change this to a download button, how will users close the lightbox?  I think it makes more sense to add a download button rather than change the function of the existing button.

Comment: Good question. I thought of making the 'title' a download button, but that seemed very difficult (back then). I realised I could instruct people to click outside the lightbox DIV to close it, which doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: Yet, I discovered how to put a active link inside the 'title' while using a PHP script for the downloads (which also logs them. Very sweet). I also modded the `title` element so it wouldn't be shown when hovering over the link. This is now `data-title`.

`data-title="&lt;a href=&quot; download.php?f=', $dir , '/', $file, '&quot;&gt;Click to download&lt;/a&gt;"`

PHP script can be found here: (http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/download.php)